# Changes to default margin width of NSLayoutConstraint in iOS 8

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios8, nslayoutconstraint

Using the visual formatting language, the following constraint string would produce a 20pt margin on iOS 7.

`|-[someView]-|`

With iOS 8, this same constraint results in margins closer to 5pt.

Where is this change documented and what is the purpose/context of the change?

Comment: I believe you are looking for the description of [layoutMargins](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/layoutMargins). The default value is naturally going to change between releases of iOS as the overall style changes.